# PHP syntax explanation

Tags: php, string, syntax

How can I translate to PHP syntax something like that:

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])//but q=is not empty or <2 because in this case redirect to) { do this } else { do this one }
```

I hope it's not too massy.

Thanks.

**updated question**

Why this code does not redirect ?

```
    if(isset($_GET['q']))
{ 
    if(!empty($_GET['q']) || $_GET['q']>2)
    {

    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $sql = $db->prepare ('SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = :a');
    $sql->bindParam(':a',$q);
    $sql->execute();

    }

    else

    {

      header("Location:somepage.php");

    }

} else {

$sql = $db->prepare ('SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY b');
$sql->execute();

}
```

Comment: How does your URL querystring look like ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran href="./page.php?q=<? php echo $i; ?>"

Comment: There is a space between `<?` and `php` .. Remove that and give a shot.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran no way

Comment: Your code redirects if your URL is like `page.php?q=` which means there is no value passed for `q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q']))
{
    if(!empty($_GET['q']) || $_GET['q']<2)
    {
        header("location:somepage.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Cannot be redirected";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code redirects if your URL is like `page.php?q=` which means there is no value passed for `q` ...because that is how the code logic is written. If you want the logic to be act the other way change the `!empty` to `empty` on the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

What? Do you mean the code for the "text" you have?

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && (!empty($_GET['q']) || $_GET['q'] < 2)) {
  // redirect here using header("location: foo.php") or some other function if you are using some framework.
}
else {
  /otherwise do something else.
}
```

**Update to your updated question:**

Because `$_GET['q']` isn't empty? Do a `var_dump` of `$_GET` so we, and you, know what's in there. It's impossible to tell otherwise. But I think your code is doing exactly what you have told it to do. You just don't have the complete picture of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `q` is a number here.

```
if (isset($_GET['q']) {
    if (empty($_GET['q'] || $_GET['q'] < 2)) {
        // do redirect here
    } else {
        // do mysql here
    }
}
```